# Off topic or duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have seen a lot of questions all over Stack Exchange which have a lot of upvotes but are completely against the rules (e.g: [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) and [What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before)). I actually like these questions and I think it's good that they're not deleted or whatever.

However I've seen some questions actually duplicating the things that are already answered/asked in one of those questions. Now I've seen some just being closed as off topic (while I think this might be confusing to new people) like: [How to get started learning Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/im-dying-to-learn-chinese). Others are closed as a duplicate ([Where to master HTML, CSS and Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29396/where-to-master-html-css-and-javascript)).

What should be done with these questions? Close as duplicate or off-topic?

**Off-topic:**
I know the Chinese Stack Exchange question might be a weird example since it's a Stack Exchange that's not really popular, but I've seen more on other Stack Exchange websites like this which are closed as off-topic. About the duplicate ones, you can find a lot of them if you just look at linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the questions you link to are **community-wikis**. This means the information is regularly updated and added to *by the community*.

They are attempts to be canonical questions which are asked quite often on that particular site, but are off-topic. If you see the 'Linked' questions in the sidebar, you'll see there are *loads!* - This is because these questions are always linked to when someone asks, a helpful, but off-topic question.

So, the community wiki questions should (and will) stay. If you see questions that are off-topic that *aren't community wiki*, then flag/vote to close, **if possible as a dupe to a previously made canonical question.**

The already existing *duplicates* pointing towards the community wikis should also stay - because duplicates help other users find what they want - they often contain different words that other people type whilst searching for something.

Comment: Did you read the question though? I know the community wiki should and will stay. Im talking about the (duplicate) questions linked with them. 90% of your post is not relevant to this.

Comment: @Loko sorry - but still, the duplicates should stay, because duplicates sometimes contain words other users type whilst searching. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah but the normal thing to do is close them. What should they be closed as? Off topic or duplicate?

Comment: I think this post does answer your question Loko. Read the final paragraph.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Yeah it does but not really a good explanation why dupe and not off topic.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ok this is a good edit to it. I'll accept it.